# SQL field data addition

Tags: sql

I am just wondering if it is possible to do something and as I cannot find any information about it:

let's say I have a field that I want to concatenate values to it:

For example

table 'test'

```
id |  name            |  surname 
01 |  georges         |  Michael
```

and I am trying to add information about this field like :

table 'test'

```
id |  name             |  surname
01 |  georges, rick    |  Michael
```

Do I need to update, insert or alter this 'test'.'name' with a second value(in this case 'rick')? Is it even possible to do that or will I need to create another related table in order to link 'rick' with 'georges'?

I know that if it is possible I will have to "insert" the comma as well but I do not know how.

Comment: Is `rick` also coming from another column ?

Comment: Do not store multiple values in a single row.  Use a junction table instead.

Comment: Doing this potentially fails Database Normal Forms.  IT will make scaling, querying and doing things related this name field much more difficult.  Are you sure this is the correct approach "`Concatenating`" an name to an existing record?

Comment: Any time you want to change the data in one or more columns of an existing row of data, you need to do an `UPDATE`.  I'm not sure exactly what part of this you "cannot find any information about" though.  I think you are letting the concatenation aspect confuse you.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: no 'rick' would be a new dynamic variable. I am using Mysql server. To Gordon Linoff and xbert : Do you guys think this way of doing is not ACID compliant ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server:

```
UPDATE test SET name = name + ', Rick' WHERE id = '01'
```

If you need to pull Rick from another table, you could do something like this:

```
UPDATE t
SET t.name = t.name + ', ' + o.othername
FROM test t
JOIN othername o ON t.id = o.id
WHERE t.id = '01'
```

And if you were looking for further posts/info on the topic, I'd suggest googling *sql server string concatenation*

Comment: Note `+` for string concatenation is not valid standard SQL and **only** applies to SQL Server. The same is true for the `FROM` clause in the `UPDATE` statement

Comment: Good point, thanks. I could swear I saw a sql_server tag on this originally! I must admit I remember seeing a mysql tag as well, hence my specification of SQL Server.